# worklight Direct Update error on IOS

Tags: ios, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-server, mobilefirst-server, mobilefirst-studio

We have one worklight app in production with Android and iOS environment.
Yesterday we deployed updated wlapp to production, and Android users are getting the update promptly and able to successfully updating the app.

**In iOS environment behavior is as follows**

1. User is prompted to download update
2. Users are able to download update
3. While unpacking the update one error occurs and the update fails

**Note:

Worklight Version used : 7.0

Fix pack installed : 7.0.0.0-MFPF-StudioP2-IF201607121346.zip**

Comment: What error you getting while unpack ?? Any client side logs ??

Comment: Provide device logs, and let us know if this was working earlier and you see the issue only now

Comment: Unfortunately there is no client logs since it is a production build,  and newly downloaded app is not getting this issue

Comment: This was working earlier

Comment: @user3458301 You can capture client side logs using [iOS Console](https://lemonjar.com/iosconsole/) if you have app where you can reproduce this issue. Also i would recommend you to open a PMR with IBM on this issue.

Comment: @user3458301 I'm facing the same issue as well and from our investigation it looks like something is being cashed on iOS causing the unpacking to fail. Because of that we don't use direct update at all in our PROD as we submit to store all the time unless we have a major security issue that must be pushed immediately and not waiting for App store reviews.